# how to poistion the ajax html extender hyperlink popup window in centre and how to validate the URL?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I implemented the latest Ajax html extender in my application.  When I click the hyperlink manager tool, it will open the window for entering URL in left, side corner of the screen in IE.  But in Firefox or Chrome, it is positioned in center of the screen.  Is there any other way to customize the popup window?

Also how do I validate url in a textbox after submitting?  Can we customize it using jquery or javascript or c# server side?

Answer (score 1):

Try css rules:

```
.popup{
width:200px;
height:100px;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-left:-100px;/*half of width*/
margin-top:-50px;/*half of height*/
}
```

If width is not defined, you can easily get counted width with JS and change css properties. Or if you dont wanna loose the time you can use FancyBox plugin (this is my choice among others lightboxes).

Comment: where do i apply this style ? do we have seperate css file for ajax html extender?

Comment: For popup container div. Of course if popup window is not a browser window.